# Setting up my BFGMiner with two AMD GPU's

Tags: miner-configuration, gpu, bfgminer

I have two AMD Radeon 7770's in my rig. I am able to get the command prompt of `BFGMiner` to run fine up, to the point where I need to add my devices (GPU's). I am not sure what commands to use or where I can find the instructions I need. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: have you installed the amd sdk drivers to run it? have you enabled gpu mining? what coin are you mining? what pool are you mining? lots more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the `Readme - GPU`?

I have pasted the contents at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KKfyspvD), if you wanna check it out?